# Pass a big number parameter to kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to pass a virtual address parameter (e.g. 0xf23fa44) to a small kernel module.

I obtain: `Numerical result out of range` error regardless of parameter type I use (int, long). Unsigned int & unsigned long gives a compilation error.

How can I solve this problem ?

Here as my source code:

```
#include <...headers...>

static long address = 0;
module_param(address, long, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

static int hello_init(void){
    struct task_struct *task_struct = (struct task_struct*) address;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "----BEGIN-------\n");
    printk("pid: %x\n" task_struct->pid)    
    printk(KERN_ALERT "----END-------\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){

    printk(KERN_ALERT "----EXIT---------\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean by "passing parameter to kernel module". Is it like a `insmod modname.ko param=0xf23fa44`? If so, show the code of the module (how it defines the parameter).

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. I don't the source with me. Basically, I use module_param(my_long, long,...)

Comment: I added the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of macro `module_param`:

```
Standard types are:
     byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong
     charp: a character pointer
     bool: a bool, values 0/1, y/n, Y/N.
     invbool: the above, only sense-reversed (N = true).
```

For C type `unsigned long` corresponded value of *type* argument for `module_param` is `ulong`:

```
static unsigned long address = 0;
module_param(address, ulong, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution; you could use a string instead

```
static char *str_name = "1231241233213213123123423";
module_param(str_name,charp,0000);
```

And parse the string into whatever type will fit the value.